# Is this combination of forms correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verb-forms

I ran into this particular sentence today:

> They shouldn't work more than they are now.

Though, I'd expect this sentence to be expressed as:

> They shouldn't work more than they work now.

or:

> They shouldn't be working more than they are now.

Is my conception of English wrong on that particular point or is the former sentence incorrect?

Comment: General Reference. The simplest change needed to make the first sentence valid is *They shouldn't work more than they **do** now*.

Comment: Oh right, your form is definitely better than my first edit proposal :) Do you have any formal backup so that I can better argue my point? Thanks!

Comment: You starting sentence is invalid, as you presumably realise. But there's nothing "wrong" with your suggested alternatives, and my version isn't "better" than either - it's just the smallest change needed to fix the original.

Comment: Although the the first form is not valid grammatically (work is something you *do*, not something you *are*), it does show up in hasty speech sometimes, where I would interpret it as a present progressive: "They shouldn't work more than they are [working] now."

Comment: @downvoter: please provide comments about why you think this question is bad so that I can improve it

Comment: Ok, 3 downvotes, no comment. I guess that was my first and last question on that site...

Answer (score 3):

A problem with that first sentence is that *are* does not belong with that form of *work*.  Substitute *do* and that sentence becomes acceptable: “They shouldn’t work more than they do now.’

Comment: This answer doesn't add much to FumbleFingers comment, so I'd rather have him post it if there's no further point to be made.

Comment: That's fine. My thought was that testing the secondary verb (are) with "work" is a quick way to flush out what made the sentence seem awkward.